# Provided next available para id is already registered

Tags: parachain, rococo

Background - I have relay chain setup that is able to connect to local rococo testnet, and I am trying to obtain and register unique para_id on Rococo testnet via the polkadotjs app. I have provided the next available id as described in the document, but we received an error that it's already registered.

Details of the error are below:

it is assigning me 2015 ID which is already in use.
[image] [image]
I need to know that how I register a unique paraID? or how I can find my paraID is unique?

Can someone please guide where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6):

There seems to be an inconsistency between the parachains and the registrar. The Rococo state indeed refers to 2015 as the next free id, and it is indeed already assigned -

[image: current nextFreeId]

(This part edited from the comment below, the original comment for calling `register` was incorrect)

Since the UI button only calls `registrar.reserve()` here and the logic is all handled by the runtime, it certainly points to an inconsistency. Internally [`reserve` gets the next free id](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/b9d52210c1a0b2d9ea7eae3bec8a8cb57666f854/runtime/common/src/paras_registrar.rs#L344-L350)

Where it fails then is in [`do_reserve`](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot/blob/b9d52210c1a0b2d9ea7eae3bec8a8cb57666f854/runtime/common/src/paras_registrar.rs#L488) checking the lifecycle.

So in this case I would suggest `sudo` to do an adjustment of that next_free storage location - since it maps to something already registered, it cannot move forward.

Comment: I tried the same that you are suggested but getting an error "registrar.NotReserved". I have made multiple attempts but getting the same error each time. And also on every attempt I lose 98 ROC as a submission fee.
Error Screenshot:- https://imgur.com/OusloSs 
Any more suggestions you may have?

Comment: Umpf, I made a mistake above :( Need to call `reserve` in the same module. (`register` is for after the id is available...) Will update the post.

Comment: ... however, internally `reserve()` gets the next free id as well, so you will end with the same issue. So I believe the state needs to be cleaned here... at least based on my reading of the situation. And actually the "UI button" does nothing more than call `reserve`, so the outcome would be the same...

Comment: Yeah getting an error again i.e. "registrar.AlreadyRegistered "
Error Screenshot:- https://imgur.com/b7sUZEV

Comment: Indeed, as linked to the code and explained in the updated answer, the state for next free doesn't match.

Comment: Try now :) Sudo adjusted the nextFreeId and it is running again. The discrepancy came into play since parachains are being manually registered to match up with their Kusama ids.