# next available para id is already registered

Tags: parachain

it wont let us register a parachain id on rococo the nextFreeId is "3,026" and its already taken from Bajun Network

"system.ExtrinsicFailed
registrar.AlreadyRegistered" when tx is submitted

https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frococo-rpc.polkadot.io#/parachains/parathreads

the chain would need sudo intervention to fix the slots and we can't post a issue on subport. See here for a previous occurrence of the same issue - [Provided next available para id is already registered](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/provided-next-available-para-id-is-already-registered)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem is now resolved

Answer (score 1):

This will be resolved on Rococo shortly by moving to give out IDs of higher number than already registered ones, likely in the 4000s. I will also [opened up blank issues](https://github.com/paritytech/subport/commit/15249b284327ed5d516fd4f09b07ee9b1a9cc9e8) on subport for Rococo specifically.

Comment: Seems to be all ok now - the nextFreeId is 4,000 now. (Checked by querying the state)