# ROCOCO next Para-ID is registered and seem to be "lost in space"

Tags: rococo, paraid

The next available `para-id` = 4290

`para-id` 4290 is showing in Overview but lighter shade (lost in space?)

this is not a new issue (have seen it reported in Jun 2022.

how do we proceed? thank you

Comment: The para-id 4290 is registered as a parachain, I am going to investigate why the next available para-id is still 4290. Where did you see it reported the last time it happen?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for that has to be some forced sudo operation, otherwise that is not a possible state.

Thanks for flagging this, it has now been addressed.

In respect to

> para-id 4290 is showing in Overview but lighter shade (lost in space?)

My understanding is that polkadot-js/apps greys out parachains that are not producing blocks or their nodes are not reachable.

Answer (score 0):

thank you but i don't think it has been resolved. i am trying to request for a para-id and 4290 is showing up but when i tried to register it, it says it has been registered and it doesn't go through.

same problem as below :  "registrar.AlreadyRegistered "

[Provided next available para id is already registered](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1418/provided-next-available-para-id-is-already-registered)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Try again, maybe you have dispatched your call before the changes made effect

Comment: thank you, just tried and it works now!